# How to make a column in a datagrid a checkbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is this

[image: First pic]

The Result I want to achieve is this

[image: Second Pic]

But Everytime I run my code with the stored procedure it becomes like this
[image: Third Pic]

There are the code to populate the table

```
private void btnReturnSearch_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvCurrentBorrowed.DataSource = db.sp_ViewBorrowedEquipment(int.Parse(txtReturnID.Text));
    }
```

This the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC sp_ViewBorrowedEquipment
(
    @TransactionID int
)
as
SELECT TBLEQUIPMENTDETAILS.EQUIPMENT_ID as 'ID', TBLEQUIPMENTDETAILS.EQUIPMENT_NAME as 'Name', TBLBORROWED.Quantity, TBLBORROWED.IsGoodCondition as 'Returned?', TBLBORROWED.IsGoodCondition AS 'Good Condition?' FROM TBLBORROWED
INNER JOIN TBLEQUIPMENTDETAILS ON TBLBORROWED.EQUIPMENT_ID=TBLEQUIPMENTDETAILS.EQUIPMENT_ID
INNER JOIN TBLTRANSACTION ON TBLBORROWED.TransactionID=TBLTRANSACTION.TransactionID
WHERE TBLTRANSACTION.TransactionID=@TransactionID
```

Any Comments or Any Ideas would really help

Comment: It looks like your grid's AutoGenerateColumns property is true, make it false.

Comment: Crowcoder is correct, in addition you need to set each grid column’s `DataPropertyName` to “match/equal” the column name in the `DataSource.`